# Restangular - Removing property from element

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Im trying to remove a property element before doing the submission of that element.

```
$scope.changeTitle = function(song, title){
    song.title = title;
    delete song.label;

    song.put();
}
```

When doing so it seems that the property "label" is removed. When I do the PUT operation the object actually has the property label.

```
// This is the object I'm sending (checked from the chrome dev tool - network)
{
  artist: "XXXXX"
  title: 'XX'
  label: []
}
```

Is there any way to remove a property from an element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect the object's `put` method in Developer console, you'll find that the referenced object is actually your original object (even after changes). In order fix the reference, use `Restangular.copy()` before you manipulate the object.

Earlier when you wrote something along the lines of:

```
$scope.song = restangular.one(song, 1).get().$object;
```

You should instead write:

```
$scope.song = restangular.copy(restangular.one(song, 1).get().$object);
```

To see the related issue, checkout: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/55

Comment: that was the solution I ended up doing, copying the data, doing changes over the copy and submitting those. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [underscore's](http://underscorejs.org/) `_.omit` function (http://underscorejs.org/#omit)

```
song = _.omit(song,'label');
```